# What is meant by tag follower versus the "x number" that appears after a tag name?

Tags: support, tags, faq-proposed, followers

This screenshot should demonstrate the two different items. There is a tag, a "x number" and a set of followers. What do the different numbers mean?

[image: Demonstrates tagged versus x #]

This question comes courtesy of a [chat dialog](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/conversation/whats-the-difference-between-a-tag-x-and-a-tag-follower) from the SO Tavern on chat.stackexchange.com

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 12):

The number you see is the sum of the number of people following the tag via email, plus the number of people that have added the tag to their favorites.

A tag follower is someone who wants to receive daily email summaries of new questions in that tag. You can follow a tag by clicking the "subscribe" link on that pop-up.

The "x *number*" indicates how many questions have that particular tag. The most popular tags are on tens of thousands of questions.

For more details on this pop-up, see: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/

Comment: There are only two numbers, not three. I'm confused.

Comment: 30471 in the example is the "x number". The "12.6k" is "the sum of the number of people following the tag via email, plus the number of people that have added the tag to their favorites.".