# Lost space in tag hover popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, popups

There [was a space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76828/what-is-meant-by-tag-follower-versus-the-x-number-that-appears-after-a-tag-nam) between the actual number and the text "followers" in tag hover popup. The poor space character is now gone. Is that intentional?

Current popup:

[image: Screenshot of current popup]

Comment: This seems to only be happening on Meta.

Comment: I put money it's yet another localization bug... @Oded probably a dev still didn't deploy it network wide.

Comment: That poor space, wandering alone through the echoing corridors of meta. It's enough to make anyone sad to think of it :-).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nope. I have deployed everywhere. Strange that only Meta is displaying the issue. The source code has the space. Weird.

Comment: This issue came up in rev `2013.9.17.1431` but it is not in `2013.9.17.1017` which is running on Stack Overflow (or atleast which I am seeing on my browser ... maybe cached)

Comment: @AzizShaikh - they happen to be the same source code, at least for this.

Comment: @Oded at first I thought client side script was messing up with the raw results, but [those raw results](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/subscriber-info) also don't contain the poor space: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c9GdA.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some localization code went wonky and was collapsing the space when it shouldn't have.

I blame him:

> [image]

Fixed.